# Android in app billing verification

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

Hello I'm trying to build an app with an in app purchase for an upgrade inside the app. And I was wondering how can I verify that the purchase was not made via freedom. And was really from Google Play server. also. I've read this  [Protecting in-app purchases from Freedom Hack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21966369/925083) But it says that I should have server and I rather not. Because I'm not sure if my app will go popular. And if not. I'm gonna waste money on hosting. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The security is not granted if you use only client-side mechanism. The only thing you can do is to put a good level of protection but you can't be sure is ok, usually it's good for lazy hackers but you can't do anything if someone with a good background wants to crack your app. If your app is not popular, however, at least at the beginning you can go as I said.

Comment: I'm talking specific about freedom